# Error: Cannot find module 'tap'

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, chai

Got this error;

```
> weather-app@1.0.0 test C:\Users\Ofirs\Desktop\n-4-11-chaining
> mocha **/*.test.js

module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'tap'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
```

when trying to run mocha by "npm run test-watch" here is my package.json file:

```
{
"name": "weather-app",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "test.js",
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha **/*.test.js",
    "test-watch": "nodemon --exec \"npm test\""
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "yargs": "^4.8.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "mocha": "^4.1.0",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0"
}
}
```

please help me to find the problem. peace

Comment: No need to help the problem was fixed. I have just added another '*' right after "mocha".

Comment: Please post your answer and accept it yourself as the best answer. That will mark the question as solved in SO, and still allow other people to suggest different answers.

Comment: Down vote : you post no answer to your question or delete your question

Answer (score 0):

No need to help the problem was fixed. I have just added another '*' right after "mocha".

Comment: Can you elaborate? perhaps show the exact string that works?

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```
"mocha */*.test.js"
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: We just check for first * as folder name than second * for file names